# Django change extablished column with values into a ForeignKey

Tags: python, django, model

I have the following model in place:

```
class IssueDescription(models.Model):
    no = models.CharField(max_length=10, primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False)
    confirm = models.TextField()
    remedy = models.TextField()
    subsystem = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False)
```

It already lives in Postgres DB, and is populated with values. The values held in it came from a .csv file (including subsystem values).
What I realized, is that I would like to make `subsystem` column into a ForeignKey, and move all the values from it into a separate table, e.g.:

```
class Subsystems(models.Model):
    subsystem = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False)

class IssueDescription(models.Model):
    no = models.CharField(max_length=10, primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False)
    confirm = models.TextField()
    remedy = models.TextField()
    subsystem = models.ForeignKey(Subsystems, on_delete=models.PROTECT, blank=False)
```

What would be the cleanest way of moving already established values in the original IssueDescription model's `subsystem` column to a newly created Subsystems table, and drawing all the links via ForeignKey field in a new IssueDescription model?

Answer (score 0):

Were it me, I'd do this through the Django shell. You could write the pk and subsystem field of each IssueDescription instance out to a json file then, after updating your models, use that same json file to create and update both models.

```
python manage.py shell

from your_app.models import IssueDescription
import json

all_issues = IssueDescription.objects.all()
migrate_items = []

for issue in all_issues:
    migrate_items += {id: issue.id, subsystem: issue.subsystem}

with open("migrate_file.txt", "w") as outfile:
    json.dump(migrate_items, outfile, indent=4)
```

Then go ahead and make your changes, make migrations and migrate. Aftwards, back to the shell...

```
python manage.py shell

from your_app.models import IssueDescription, Subsystems
import json

with open("migrate_file.txt", "r") as f:
   data = json.load(f)

for row in data:
    subsys = Subsystems(subsystem=row["subsystem"])
    subsys.save()
    issue = IssueDescription.objects.get(id=row["id"]
    issue.subsystem = subsys
    issue.save()
```

Haven't tested this, so might require a couple minor tweaks, but I think this would do the trick.